# Output of lowpass filter with damped sine wave input

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, linear-systems, homework, stochastic

> The random process $$Y(t)=\cos(\omega_0t)\cos(\omega_0t+\pi N(t))$$where $N(t)$ is a Poisson process of parameter $\lambda$ enters a lowpass filter with transfer function $$H(j\omega) =
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   1  & \mbox{if } |\omega| \leq \frac{\omega_0}{2} \\
>   0  & \mbox{if } |\omega| \geq \frac{\omega_0}{2}
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$ If $Z(t)$ is the output of the filter, find the expectation and variance of both $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$.

So, first we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]=\cos(\omega_0t)\mathbb{E}[\cos(\omega_0t+\pi N(t))]=\cos(\omega_0t)\mathbb{E}[\cos(\omega_0t)\cos(\pi N(t))-\sin(\omega_0t)\sin(\pi N(t))]]=\cos^2(\omega_0t)\mathbb{E}[\cos(\pi N(t))]$$

Doing that expectation by definition (with the summation) we get that $$\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]=\cos^2(\omega_0t)e^{-2\lambda t}$$

With a similar procedure we find that

$$\mathbb{V}[Y(t)]=\cos^4(\omega_0t)\cdot(1-e^{-4\lambda t})$$

First I tried to find $\mathbb{E}[Z(t)]=h(t)*\mathbb{E}[Y(t)]$

So using the property that states that the transform of $x(t)y(t)$ is $\frac{1}{2\pi}X(j\omega)Y(j\omega)$ we get that

$$\mathcal{F}(\cos^2(\omega_0t))=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega+2\omega_0)+\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega-2\omega_0)+\pi\delta(\omega)$$

But it is known that the transform of the exponential multiplied by the step function (the random process involved is valid only for $t>0$ by the definition of the Poisson process probability function) is $\frac{1}{2\lambda+j\omega}$ so

$$\mathcal{F}(y(t))=Y(j\omega)=\frac14\frac{1}{2\lambda+j(\omega+2\omega_0)}+\frac14\frac{1}{2\lambda+j(\omega-2\omega_0)}+\frac12\frac{1}{2\lambda+j\omega}$$

So what I need would be to antitransform $H(j\omega)Y(j\omega)$, and now I'm stuck. How could this be done? And regarding $\mathbb{V}[Z(t)]$, I have no idea of how to even begin to solve it.

Comment: You can either solve in the frequency domain by taking Laplace transform of y(t) = Y(s) and then multiply with H(s), then take inverse Laplace transform, OR you can solve in the time domain by noting that h(t) is a sinc function, and convolving that sinc function with y(t).

Comment: Is $y(t)$ defined for $-\infty<t<\infty$?

Comment: @DanBoschen: The problem with the suggested Laplace transform approach is that $Y(s)$ doesn't exist, neither does $H(s)$. A solution could be to use the Fourier transform instead (we already have $H(\omega)$), but  we still have a problem with $Y(\omega)$, unless the OP forgot to add a step function to the definition of $y(t)$. In the latter case, the problem can be solved using the Fourier transform, but it still can't be solved using the Laplace transform (I've assumed that $\lambda\neq 0$).

Comment: The square in the term will give $y(t)$ [a DC and a component at $2 \omega_0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E2(x)). With $e^{-x}$ in, we get [a damped cosine with an offset](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E2(x)*exp(-x)). The ideal lowpass $H(\omega)$ would take out the component at $2 \omega$ and leave the $e^{-x}$ envelope. I would go down the [Fourier route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions) too. @MattL. It could be assumed that they "start" at the same time (step at $t=0$) (?)

Comment: @A_A: Well, that's the question I was asking the OP. Note that you also assume that $\lambda$ is real-valued and positive. It shouldn't be us assuming all those things, but the OP should clarify the question.

Comment: @MattL. I have edited my question. $\lambda$ is real and positive and the signal is multiplied by the step function.

Comment: Are you sure that this is exactly the problem that you need to solve? No extra information, etc.? Because if this is the exercise then the solution is difficult. You could just write the inverse Fourier transform integral (with limits $\pm \omega_0/2$ due to the low pass filter), and that's it. I don't think that there's a closed form solution.

Comment: @MattL. The original problem is that there is a random process $X(t)=\cos(\omega_0t+\pi N(t))$ where $N(t)$ is a Poison Process. Then the signal is multiplied by $\cos(\omega_0t)$ and that is what enters the filter (what I called $y(t)$ in the question). I want to find the expectation value for the output of the filter, and that's how I got to the original question I posted above.

Comment: @MattL. Good point about assumptions. (Do you mean to say "...then the solution is easy", further above by the way?). Tendero, what you describe in the comment is not what appears in the question. But, in any case, what you describe is modulation, so the output of the LP will be proportional to $N(t)$. Please see [this link](http://kom.aau.dk/group/05gr506/report/node29.html#SECTION061412000000000000000)

Comment: @A_A: No, I don't think the solution is easy in any case. Even with $\lambda=0$ you don't get "some deltas in the frequency domain", as the OP assumes.

Comment: @Tendero: I would suggest that you reformulate the question to reflect the original problem, instead of the derived one. There might be a path to the solution that you don't foresee now.

Comment: @MattL. I have edited the question with the original problem in it.

Comment: @Tendero The following statement: "So using the property that states that the transform of x(t)y(t) is 12πX(jω)Y(jω) we get that"  .  Is wrong and keeps throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this out thanks to a friend of mine. The thing is that $N(t)$ can be even or odd, and in both cases, the signal we get is easy to deal with.

We can calculate the desired expectation this way:

$$\mathbb{E}[Z(t)]=\mathbb{E}[h(t)*Y(t)]=\mathbb{E}[h(t)*Y(t)|N(t) =2n]\mathbb{P}[N(t)=2n]+\mathbb{E}[h(t)*Y(t)|N(t) =2n+1]\mathbb{P}[N(t)=2n+1]$$

But when $N(t)$ is even or odd, $Y(t)$ becomes simple:

$$Y(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \cos^2(\omega_0t)  & \mbox{if } N(t)\mbox{ is even } \\
  -\cos(\omega_0t)\sin(\omega_0t)    & \mbox{if } N(t)\mbox{ is odd }
 \end{array}
\right.$$

So

$$\mathbb{E}[Z(t)]=\mathbb{P}[N(t)=2n]\cdot h(t)*\cos^2(\omega_0t)-\mathbb{P}[N(t)=2n+1]\cdot h(t)*(\cos(\omega_0t)\sin(\omega_0t))$$

And those two probabilities are easy to calculate, as well as the two convolutions left.